# Labelling collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections: `persons` (millions) and `groups`. When creating a `group` I have a `rule`, which are actually the criteria to find `persons`. Now, what I want to do is to add the `groups` `_id` to all the matching `persons`.

The request to my API:

```
POST /groups {
    "rule": {"age": {"$gt": 18}},
    "description": "persons above 18"
}
```

On my MongoDB:

```
db.persons.find({"age": {"$gt": 18}})
```

Now I want to add the `group` `_id` to a `groups` array field in each of the matching `persons`, so that I can later get all persons in the group. Can this be done directly in the same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but a simple `update` statement should do it:

```
db.persons.update(
  { "age" : {$gt : 18} },
  { $addToSet : { "groups" : groupId }}, 
  false,  // no upsert ($addToSet and $push still add the field)
  true);  // update multiple docs in this query
```

Note that [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/operator/update/push/) will add the same value over and over, while [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) will ensure uniqueness in the array, which probably makes sense in this case.

You'll have to find/insert the group itself in a different statement, though.

Comment: Thanks. I have a short follow up: are there any (injection) risks in passing the query criteria object directly from the API input to MongoDB?

Comment: Yes, also see the MongoDB FAQ at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#javascript. You can use `$where` in queries which allows arbitrary javascript execution. Even if you managed to filter all write statements in there, one could still use an absurdly inefficient query (or simply an infinite loop) to stall your system, or create a `$where : true` clause that will cause updates to all your users which floods the database with (indexed) data, which will also drown the system.